# Is there a WiX 3.5-compatible extension dialog for SQL connections?

Tags: sql, wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix-extension

We wish to add a dialog to our WiX installer that prompts the user for a SQL server connection: server address, authentication type, and SQL login/password. A Test Connection button would be nice as well.

My searches turned up the [msiext](https://github.com/dblock/msiext) project, but I cannot reference its dlls (e.g., WixCommonUiExtension.dll) in my WiX project because they were built for WiX 3.0. Did a bit of googling and I'm [not the only user](http://msiext.codeplex.com/workitem/13649) who's experienced this issue. Folks have even tried building the msiext project against WiX 3.5 themselves, but based on the posts in that link I'd prefer not to go down that road.

Can anyone provide or point me to a dialog I can use? I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but you could try http://msiext.codeplex.com/ project. The site claims that they have such dialog

Comment: The project was moved to github and it is still actively maintained. Here is the dialog: https://github.com/dblock/msiext/blob/master/src/WixExtensions/CommonUiExtension/wixlib/RuntimeDbCredDlg.wxs